# <a href> form option? dynamic Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm pretty new to coding, so please bear with me (I don't even know if what I want to do is possible). I am trying to make a join page for a new webpage, which requires people to select multiple skills that they know how to do, and want to know how to do.

Once a skill is selected, I need a 140char box to pop up to explain. I have the database with all of the skills set setup already. There are 11 main skill groups, with many children underneath them, each will a parent_id, and specific skill_id.

I found a menu, called ["JQuery multi level accordion menu"](http://www.scriptbreaker.com/javascript/script/JQuery-multi-level-accordion-menu). I couldn't figure out how to dynamically call all of the skills, so I have just hardcoded them in there. I was able to get them listed, but not in the accordion. If anybody has any ideas, please let me know.

The main problem that I have is that I need the menu to work like a form, so that I can POST which skills have been selected, along with its 140char box. Since the menu requires the skill to be an ahref, I don't know how to turn that into a form option.  This is the first two elements of the menu....

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordian.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".topnav").accordion({
    accordion:false,
    speed: 500,
    closedSign: '[+]',
    openedSign: '[-]'
});
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

..............

                    <ul class="topnav" style="padding-top:50px;">
<li><a href="#">Academic</a>
    <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Spanish</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Research</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Politics</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">History</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Anantomy</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Phsiology</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Calculus</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Metaphors</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Physhology</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Fiction Writing</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Japanese</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Vocabulary</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Mental Disorders</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="#">Business/Career</a>
    <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Financial Planning</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Startup Advice</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>

         <li><a href="#">Networking</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Professional Skills</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Public Speaking</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Interviewing</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Managment</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Team Building</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Job Application</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Budgeting</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Advertising</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Resume Buidling</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Computer/Technology</a>
    <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Indesign</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a>
         <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dreamweaver</a>
         <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Flash</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">After Effects</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Corel Draw</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Final Cut</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Solidworks</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Alias</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Maya</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">AutoCAD</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">3DS Max</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Rhino</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Excel</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Microsoft Office</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Google Adwords</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Powerpoint</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Hacking</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">HTML</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">CSS</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">Java</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">PHP</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">MySQL</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">JQuery</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I try to load them dynamically, I use

```
  <li><a href="#">Other</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Juggling</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">R/C Cars</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Model Railroads</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">How to Drink Whiskey like a Champ</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Foursquare</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fashion</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Telling Ghost Stories</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drive Stick Shift</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Solving a Rubix Cube</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        </ul>
```

```
<li><a href="#">Test</a>
    <ul>
<?
<form> 
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("****","****","*****");
//Select database
mysql_select_db("****");

 $query = "select concat(skill_name) from ******* where parent_id = 2" or die (mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 if($result == false)
{
user_error("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query");
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
echo "<p>Sorry, no rows were returned by your query.</p>\n";
} 
else
{
while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  foreach($query_row as $key => $value)
  {
     echo "" <li><a href="#">$value</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want  to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>"";

     //echo "$value<br />\n";
  }
  echo "" <li><a href="#">$value</a><ul><li><a href="#"><textarea>What do you want to know about this subject?</textarea><input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Submit" /></a></li>
            </ul></li>"";


  //"<br />\n";
}
} 

?>
</ul>
</li>
                </div>
```

Any Ideas? If I didn't include any necessary code, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an anchor tag to perform POST requests, you need to look at the `jQuery.post()` method. If you want it to perform form submissions, there's the `submit()` method. Check out the jQuery docs to see how both work, but from the looks of your code, since you don't have an actual `<form>` you will most likely need `jQuery.post`

In either case, what you need is a click event listener on your anchor tags. So something like:

```
<script>
jQuery("a").click(function(evt) {
        //this function gets called every time an <a> tag is clicked
        //evt contains information about the event
        //look at it in Chrome Developer tools to see it
        console.log(evt); //logging the event object so you can see what it contains
        jQuery.post(YOUR CODE HERE);
});
</script>
```

Sorry if I've oversimplified anything (you said you're new to coding).